# How to remove last text after / from location.href using jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to remove `#step_4#step_4#step_4` from my local
project link

`https://localhost/test-project/#step_4#step_4#step_4` using `window.location.href`.

I have done below code for that

```
var url_id = window.location.href;
var url_id_value = url_id.split('#')[1];
console.log(url_id.split('#')[1]);
```

But I just got `step_4` in console.

But I want to store a value `https://localhost/test-project/` in variable using `window.location.href` or is there any other way to store that value in variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line of code `var url_id_value = url_id.split('#')[1];` with the following:

```
var url_id_value = url_id.substr(0, url_id.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```